# R-Studio on OSX can't load mosaic package

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I am running OSX 10.10, R-Studio Version 0.99.484, and R version 3.2.2.

I just made a fresh install of R and R-Studio using the installers from their respective websites. I use install.packages to install "mosaic" and then I try loading it using library, but it gives me the following error:

```
library("mosaic", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
Error : object ‘dendro_data.hclust’ is not exported by 'namespace:ggdendro'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mosaic’
```

I tried reinstalling ggdendro but nothing. Does anyone have any advice on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: According to the [check results for this package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_mosaic.html), there is an error.

Comment: The function is available but not exported. Not sure if there is a way to export it into the correct namespace... `ggdendro:::dendro_data.hclust()`

Comment: @Pascal I dont see any issues with the mac version, or am I reading the page wrong?
@drmariod I tried running the export but it did not work: `Error in as.dendrogram(model) : argument "model" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Ah yes, OSX... Anyway I get the same error on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this same error and seem to have somewhere along the way resolved it. Steps taken include:

- cleaned out my libraries (local and System)
- used Disk Utility to repair any odd permissions
- reinstalled R
- opened RStudio and imported package with dependencies from the repository:

> ```
> > install.packages("mosaic", lib="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
> ```

- console prompted me to choose the older precompiled package or the newer, I chose older

> Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
>   y/n: n

- mosaic loaded happily

> ```
> > library("mosaic", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
> ```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Not sure if they fixed something at the source or if it was a temporary glitch but it worked!